# Dual Quasi-Newton Optimization on Zero Heavy Data (in SAS)

Tags: optimization, sas, zero-inflation

I am using PROC FMM in SAS, in attempt to use hurdle models on a data set with many zeros. There is one response variable and it's continuous, there are ~90 predictors (continuous - but contain many zeros) and roughly 160 000 records. When I tried running this procedure, I was told

"WARNING: Dual Quasi-Newton optimization cannot be completed. NOTE: The Dual Quasi-Newton optimization technique needs more than 200 iterations or 2000 function calls. Error: No final model fitted because no 'best' model can be determined."

I then tried this same process with fewer variables and the optimization process  worked (I think). What possible reasons could there be for this? Additionally, does anyone recommend other prediction/discrimination techniques to use in heavy zero data sets?

Comment: Although this question is asked in the context of SAS, this seems to be a statistical issue. IMO, this can be considered on topic here.

Comment: Sometimes such behavior can be due to just one or a small number of variables.  Have you tried to narrow down the scope of the problem by exploring the effects of adding and removing variables?

Comment: Paul Allison's SAS proceedings paper on Convergence Failures in Logistic Regression contains insights that are generalizable to many other maximum likelihood rooted SAS Procs as well as other software.

http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/forum2008/360-2008.pdf

Answer (score 2):

It's the curse of dimensionality. Luckily, SAS can actually throw an error. With any type of non-linear optimization, you must realize more sophisticated models lead to highly irregular likelihoods that toss general optimizers all over the place.

Why not use a quasipoisson model?